# Split Koa router and controller in multiple files

Tags: typescript, koa

I'm trying to split my application.
Unfortunately it does not work to call the controller. As soon as I comment out the controller and the post method it works to call the server.

**route/image.ts**

```
const imageController = require('../controllers/imageController.ts')

module.exports = ({ router }) => {
  router
    .get('/image', ctx => {
      ctx.body = 'Image'
    })
    .post('/image', imageController.newImage)
}
```

**controller/imageController.ts**

```
import { BaseContext } from 'koa'

export default class imageController {
  static newImage = (ctx: BaseContext) => {
    // return OK status code
    ctx.status = 200
    ctx.body = 'Test'
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Unexpected token {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        11:44:42

  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { BaseContext } from 'koa'
  ^

  SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
  at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
  at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
  at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:684:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? "Does not work" is hard to diagnose!

Comment: @Evert I have updated the description. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggest that you are trying to run your typescript files *without* typescript. The line `import { x } from 'y';` is not valid in your node.js version, and given that you are importing a type... typescript would have removed that line.

So make sure you run `tsc` and you run your `.js` files, not your `.ts` files.

Comment: First, thank you. That was the solution!
Two more questions:
import { BaseContext } from 'koa'. How can i do this with require because import outside a module is not allowed.
And how do you import the router and set it as type for the router prop to remove the implicit typing.

Comment: @F4ll0ut if you have more questions, you should open up a new one with more information and code samples